# Can't print remotely with "lpr" command unless I log in to remote Mac

Tags: mac, command-line, bash, printing, authentication

I have remote access to a Mac and I'm trying to print over command line using `lpr`.

However, the command is stuck until I log in to the remote Mac and press an icon to confirm the password already stored in Keychain.

Can I print remotely without logging in to the remote Mac?

Comment: Could you show us the exact command you are using and any errors that come back.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. An alternative method, if both Macs reside on the same network, would be to share the printer connected to the remote Mac, see https://support.apple.com/en-sa/guide/mac-help/mchlp2424/mac for details.

Comment: @TonyWilliams The command used is just $ lpr <fllename>, no error return, but nothing print out. [$ lpq returns queue correctly: LabPrinter is ready and printing// Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size// active  Mark  125     copy.sh  1024 bytes]. Then when I login mac physically, there is a pop-up window ask authentic for the printer, with user name and password already filled in. However, I have to press the confirm icon, which step I find no way to do remotely.

Comment: @jaume The URL says it's for non-network printer. The printer I use is a network printer itself. However, it cannot be accessed by Ubuntu. So I try to use a remote Mac as a medium to access printer.

Comment: Yes, it states it is for non-network printers, but you can still share it and give it a try. What is the printer manufacturer and model and your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @jaume I tried share the printer from mac, but job status shows held for authentication. Then I right click the job and click "authenticate", but no respond. The Ubuntu version is 14.04, the mac is not directly linked to printer, but print to a mps system provieded by HP via samba.